# Latest Update of Eclipse and Android SDK (March) Crashing Applications On Launch

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed the latest version of the Android SDK and Eclipse,

- Android SDK Tools - 22.6.2
- Android SDK Platform-tools - 19.0.1
- Android SDK Build-tools - 19.0.3

Eclipse is now forcing the use of fragments and code that I had working before is now not working at all, in fact its crashing the app on launch.

I created a new android app, placed a button on the screen and tried to link the code to the button and use a setOnClickListener which I have used in my previous apps before the update and now I get a whole bunch of errors that I do not know how to fix.

In the code below, the setOnClickListener for the button is crashing the app, if I comment out the listener the app launches, but obviously I have no code behind the button to do anything so it is just the GUI.

I had a Google around and couldn't find anything that was related to my problem.

Where am I going wrong/what am I doing wrong and how can I get my app launching with code?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.newandroidapplication.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.newandroidapplication.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.newandroidapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    private Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            // If I comment out the listener here, the app launches
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I'm Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat Log**

```
04-03 13:58:29.223: D/AndroidRuntime(3351): Shutting down VM
04-03 13:58:29.223: W/dalvikvm(3351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d8db20)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): Process: com.example.newandroidapplication, PID: 3351
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newandroidapplication/com.example.newandroidapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at com.example.newandroidapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-03 13:58:29.223: E/AndroidRuntime(3351):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Eclipse is now forcing the use of fragments

No, it doesn't "force" you to use fragments. It *does* try to set it up that way for you as a "convenience", though I think that depends on your target and minimum APIs (I would have to create a new project to be sure since it's been a little while).

### The way to fix it is

you can take the fragment stuff out if you don't want to use fragments. And you also don't *have* to use `FrameLayout` as it sets it up for you in the beginning. If you *want* to use fragments then you will just need to reference the `Button` appropriately.

### The reason for the crash,

as you may be aware, is because the `Button` you are trying to reference is in the fragment layout and not the `Activity` layout. But the way you are referencing the `id`, it is looking in the `Activity` layout.

Comment: Well it doesn't actually force you, but it makes it very difficult not to use a fragment. I wouldn't call it a convenience by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: @NickT it doesn't really make it difficult, IMHO, but it does create more work not to. I wouldn't call it a convenience either which is why that word was in quotes in my answer.

Comment: (+1 for getting the reason for the crash right though.)

Comment: @codeMagic Thank you very much for the help, removed all the fragment stuff and it's now working. Wasn't aware I was able to remove that and it still work